# Version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.20.3

Tags: python, numpy

I kept getting error: `ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.20.3 your numpy version is 1.18.5. Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.20.3 to use this pandas version`

And I'm unable to update, remove, and reinstall numpy.

I tried `pip install numpy` and `pip3 install numpy` and kept getting this error: `AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'`

Edit: I tried `pip install --force-reinstall numpy` and `pip install numpy==1.20.3` and still got `AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
pip install --force-reinstall numpy
and then
pip install numpy==1.20.3

Comment: I still got "AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'" as an error....